# How to connect Mysql server from another computer?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have created an application in VB (Visual Express 2013). I have successfully connected the application to Mysql localhost (same computer). But I can't connect it from another computer that is in the same network. Please help me to connect...

Comment: Is the database on remote host configured to listenen on external ip? If not you have to change the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

just replace databse connection string localhost with server's pc name or IP address

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench Community is used for other computer connecting,because localhost mysql is not supporting in that scenario.
After that version installation,you should just give connection name,host address,username and pwd,nothing touch other things.your problem will be solved.Best of luck ...:)